# can we purchase same Non Consumable In app purchase for other users using same apple id?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes

I have business models like user must have to select one plan with non consumable in app purchase at the time of registration.

But In case like, when my friends wants to use the app and he told me to register his account from my device and pay with my apple id. So I logged out my account and trying to register his account. then I can not purchase same Non Consumable In App Purchase. As Apple Id remains same.

Does anyone have idea of how to solve such instances.

Thanks,

Comment: The purchase is made by the iTunes account, so if someone else wants to register an account in your app and they want to use a different plan then they need to use *their* iTunes account to do so

Comment: can't I use same Apple account to register for other users?

Comment: If you try and purchase the same non-consumable item a second time with a particular iTunes account then the product is delivered without charge; it is essentially treated as a restoration. The same account can purchase a different in-app non-consumable